# Print a pattern that contains alternate even and odd numbers after every 10 continuous numbers

Tags: php

I want to print the following pattern i.e. within first 10 numbers should output even 
numbers and within next 10 numbers should output odd numbers and so on to a given range is given below sequentially.

```
{Like
 Even numbers
 2 4 6 8 10
 Odd numbers
 11 13 15 17 19
 Even numbers
 20 22 24 26 28 30
 Odd numbers
 31 33 35 37 39
 }
```

Comment: What have you done to solve the problem? You cannot just ask questions here and expect people to post the answer or the code.

Comment: [Merry Christmas.](https://eval.in/178351)

Answer (score 1):

You muts validate odd or even number and show it in combination of a flag '$odd' and then validate a mod 10 to get the range of 10 numbers.

************ The code:

```
//range
$start = 1;
$end = 92;
//initial status
$odd = false;
//first label
echo 'Even numbers <br/>';
for($i=$start;$i<=$end;$i++){
    //odd validation
    echo (($i&1 && $odd) ? $i.', ' : '' );
    //even validation
    echo ((!($i&1) && !$odd) ? $i.', ' : '');
    //change status and labels 
    if(($i % 10)==0){
        echo '<br/>';
        if($odd){
            echo 'Even numbers <br/>';
            $odd = false;
        }else{
            echo 'Odd numbers <br/>';
            $odd = true;
        }
    } 
}
```

************ The result:

```
Even numbers 
2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 
Odd numbers 
11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 
Even numbers 
22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 
Odd numbers 
31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 
Even numbers 
42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 
Odd numbers 
51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 
Even numbers 
62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 
Odd numbers 
71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 
Even numbers 
82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 
Odd numbers 
91,
```